# Convergence of a sequence of function defined by an integral

Tags: integration, sequences-and-series

Let $(I_n)_{n\in \mathbb{N}}$ be a sequence defined by:

> $$I_n=\int_{0}^{\infty} \dfrac{e^{-x}}{x+\frac{1}{n}}\mathrm dx.$$ Test for the convergence of this sequence.

**Here is my proof:** Note that $I_n<I_{n+1}$ so $(I_n)_{n\in \mathbb{N}}$ is increasing, but

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}I_n=\lim_{n\to\infty}\int_{0}^{\infty} \dfrac{e^{-x}}{x+\frac{1}{n}}\mathrm dx=\int_{0}^{\infty}\mathrm dx\lim_{n\to\infty}\dfrac{e^{-x}}{x+\frac{1}{n}}=\int_{0}^{\infty} \dfrac{e^{-x}}{x}\mathrm dx \tag{1}$$

The last integral does not convergence so $(I_n)_{n\in \mathbb{N}}$ is divergent.

> *Is my answer right or wrong? I'm not sure about the second equality in $(1)$.*

Comment: That's correct, justified by the monotone convergence theorem for integrals.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are correct, and you can justify it with the monotone convergence theorem. If we call $f_n(x) = e^{-x}/(x + n^{-1})$, then $f_n(x)\le f_{n+1}(x)$ for every $n$, so that by the monotone convergence theorem,
\begin{align*}
\lim \int f_n = \int\lim f_n &= \int_0^\infty \frac{e^{-x}}{x}\,dx \\
&\ge \int_0^1e^{-1}x^{-1}\,dx = \infty.
\end{align*}